# What should we do when a bounty is not totally related to the original question?

Tags: discussion, questions, bounties

In this question, *[Sec-Fetch-Mode instead of Preflight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57518225)*, someone raised a bounty on someone else's question.

The original question was about an error, and the original poster believed that his problem was related to some web standards, but it was actually a typo (the famous [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

The user who raised the bounty wrote in the bounty text that he wants details on the web standards, which is totally unrelated to the real problem of the original poster.

What should we do in this case? Should the question be edited? Is there room for the answer concerning the original poster's problem **and** the answer concerning the bounty raiser's request?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That looks indeed like it's a new question. Posting a bounty requesting an answer to a new question is just as bad as editing the question itself. Actually, it's even worse: suppose somebody answers the bountier's question; after the bounty notice disappears, future visitors won't even understand why the new answer was posted!

You should flag the question for ♦ moderator attention; they can cancel the bounty. The bounty poster will even get their reputation back. It's also nice to leave a comment on the question ([comment replies work for bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/295232)) asking them to ask a new question instead. You can't notify them on your *answer*, like somebody else did already.